# flutter splash screen with try catch

Tags: flutter

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  try {
      //---------------------------------------------->internet assscess confirm
      InternetAddress.lookup('google.com').then((vaule) async {
        result = vaule;
        if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
          if (await checkDB() == false) {
            path = await createDB(); ------------->db check
          }
          path = await getDatabasesPath();
          try {
            await Bloc.setLocationCode(); ---------->location check
          } catch (_) {
            //---------------------------//
          }
          await getValue('levelKey').then((value) {
            if (value != null) {
              ChildDrawerState.levelSwitch = value;
            } else {
              ChildDrawerState.levelSwitch = false;
            }
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>RouteMain(path)));
          });
        }
      });
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorMain()));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Image.asset(
          'image/splash-screen.gif',
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i made splash screen class and build method like above.
but problem is that build method is being recalled(rebuilt) so children Widget also is rebuilt many time how can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to

- Create your screen as Stateful
- Move accessing internet-related methods into new **async** function
- call our new **async function** by overriding initState

### Full Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  void accessInternet() async {
    try {
      //---------------------------------------------->internet assscess confirm
      InternetAddress.lookup('google.com').then((vaule) async {
        result = vaule;
        if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
          if (await checkDB() == false) {
            path = await createDB(); // ------------->db check
          }
          path = await getDatabasesPath();
          try {
            await Bloc.setLocationCode(); // ---------->location check
          } catch (_) {
            //---------------------------//
          }
          await getValue('levelKey').then((value) {
            if (value != null) {
              ChildDrawerState.levelSwitch = value;
            } else {
              ChildDrawerState.levelSwitch = false;
            }
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RouteMain(path)));
          });
        }
      });
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorMain()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    accessInternet();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Image.asset(
          'image/splash-screen.gif',
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a StatefulWidget instead and move the try-catch statement to the initState().